# Error queue and batch sending of messages

Tags: nservicebus

Hopefully this is a simple question but i need to verify that my assumption is correct: If i send 4 messages in one batch send and one of the 4 messages causes a fault and fails retries in its handler does that single message get forwarded to the error queue or does the entire batch message get placed into the error queue?

Common sense tells me that the single message would be moved to the error queue as the batch message has been unwrapped and delegated to its handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction boundary is the handler and therefore each message has its own set of retries.  The only complexity to this is that if you are using a pipeline of message handlers you also have to consider that if any of the handlers fail for a given message, a retry will occur.